# VBA IF statement for sent/not sent emails

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm using the below code to tell me when emails have been sent and display the text "sent" so I know there were no errors. But I was testing the code and I use a vlookup to display emails once I add the vendor name.  My goal is to not let the macro debug and to let it keep going on to the next but at the same time let me know there was an error on one row either because that vendor did not have an email listed and I need to fill an email in.  When I listed the vendors I left a cell blank to test code.  Even tho I have valid emails and those emails sent the VBA displays "Not sent" to the ones that were sent out.  Since the macro could not find an email due to one cell being blank it debugged and next to all the valid emails the text "Not sent" populates.  What am I missing or doing wrong? I just want to avoid debugs to tell me there is an error and just tell me that one row was "not sent" and to just keep sending the rest and populate those that do send with a "sent" text.

```
Sub Send_Multiple_Emails()
dim sh as worksheet
set sh = thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1") <-- rename to what the tabs name is

dim OA as Object
Dim msg As object

set OA = createobject("Outlook.Application")

Dim i as integer
dim last_row As Integer

last_row = application.worksheetfunction.counta(sh.range("B:B"))

for i = 2 To last_row 
Set msg = OA.createitem(0)

msg.to = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
msg.cc = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
msg.subject = sh.range("D" & i ).Value
msg.body = sh.Range("E" & i).Value

if sh.Range("F" & i).Value <> "" Then
msg.attachments.add sh.range("F" & i).Value
End If

msg.send

**If Issent = True Then
Range("G" & i).Value = "Sent"
Else
Range("G" & i).Value = "Not Sent"
End If**

next i

msgbox "Mails Sent"

End Sub
```

Comment: Without seeing how `Issent` takes a value, nobody can help you, I am afraid...  Try, please insert the next line above the piece of code you presented: `Debug.Print Issent`. You may have the surprize to see that `Issent` is `False`... Your `If ... End If` cannot be missing anything, except the case when you are looking for the result in a different sheet, while your code write 'Issent` in the **active page**...

Comment: Can you share that piece of code that modifies Issent?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes! i can add my entire vba code that i'm using it's a bit long.

Comment: @JulianG adding now!

Comment: Your code does not allocate a value to `Issent`! It is not even declared. Since it is `False`, your code does what is normal to do... But,  maybe I missed the part where `Issent` is made `True`. Can you show us where, in your code, is this happening? Did you try my suggestion to check its value before the `If ... End If` you presented?

Comment: @FaneDuru it's declared in the code, it's at the bottom. right before end sub.

Comment: I do not see any declaration and any place where it receives a value. Can you copy and paste here these lines, please? I am talking about the code you shared. Do you talk about the same one?

Comment: `If Issent = True Then
Range("G" & i).Value = "Sent"
Else
Range("G" & i).Value = "Not Sent"
End If`  that is the code i was trying to use

Comment: I am afraid, you do not make any difference between **checking** the variable value (what is happening in your code) and **giving/allocating a value to it**. Your variable will be `False` forever in the way your code treats it... This variable does not take a value from the sky when the email has been sent.

Comment: @joselyn reda: Did you try the suggestion from my answer?

Comment: @FaneDuru i am going to test now! thank you! i will get back to you ASAP!

Comment: @FaneDuru i tried the code and it works! thank you! BUT the one thing it is missing so let's say it runs into an error and the msg box pops up and it notifies me next to the email where there is an error it says not sent which is great.  I still need the code to skip the email that didn't sent and to keep sending the other emails after the error.  So if i have 10 emails listed and on line 4 there is an error i want it to skip line 4 and to keep sending emails on line 5-10.  Hope this makes sense. I appreciate your help! Getting so close!

Comment: OK. I will adapt it tomorrow...

Comment: @joselyn reda: If **you do not have any other code before `Next i`**, which we cannot see it, the code must process the next  email. I, anyhow, removed the message and reinitialize the Outlook object. Please, try it as it is now, but please, tell me if there is/are some other code line/lines between `End If` and `Next i`...

Comment: @FaneDuru there is no other code between lines "END IF" & " NEXT i". I used the updated code, it works as it did before but the macro still debugs when there is an error. When i fix the error and and rerun macro it stops at the same line right before where the error was even tho the error was corrected.  very strange.

Comment: @FaneDuru actually what I did notice from the update where you changed the msgbox to `set OA = CreateObject ("Outlook.Application")` the emails were not coming in. The macro was letting me know it was sent but when i went to check my inbox nothing was received. When i changed it back to the msgbox and reran the macro the emails came in but still not sending all emails. It still stops at the line prior to where I have a bogus error as a test.

Comment: Try the updated code, with only the last added line being commented...

Comment: @FaneDuru making that one change i receive the emails now.  I listed 4 valid emails and it only sends 3 out of the 4. which i dont understand since i tell my code where to start and end where it recognize where the row ends. by the way i really appreciate all your help!

Comment: How many emails should your application process? More then 4? Is the account which has not been sent correct? I mean, can you manually send an email to this account if you copy it from the sheet where from the code takes it?

Comment: it can vary, i created this macro because we send about 300 emails to our vendors and this template we just paste the vendor names and all these formulas within the template find the emails, exact body information it needs to send out along with an updated attachment.  Prior to that we were sending these manually it was very tedious and time consuming.  `Dim i as integer
dim last_row As Integer

last_row = application.worksheetfunction.counta(sh.range("B:B"))

for i = 2 To last_row` i added that part of the code so it knows where to start and stop. it worked prior to adding Boolean

Comment: @FaneDuru ran out of space to tag you on the comment above.

Comment: @FaneDuru been playing around with the code, is there anything you can think of as to why it would stop at a certain row?

Comment: This is something else... I answered your question but you did not tick the answer code left side check box, to make it **accepted answer**. Your problem is not connected to inserted lines. Could you understand what problem has the mail which could not be sent and raised an error? Anyhow, I will also try posting your code adapted as I believe it should be...

Comment: @FaneDuru I just ticked it.  I played around with it last night and I was trying to add a Dim "" as long code long with it.  Maybe I need to tell it to go End.Xldown but then it was going all the wayt to the bottom with no emails assigned to it.  I tested it with 20 emails and noticed that it seems to stop before the last email.  so it sent 19 emails out of 20, the code does not pick up the last row filled out.  I will try your updated code and get back to you ASAP!

Comment: So, it is not something two wrong with the code itself. Try my posted variant, please. Your code does not calculate very well the last empty row... He is also making the `msg = Nothing` after each iteration. And it will warn (on the sheet) about the (eventual) wrong path of file to be attached... Using the reference, will allow you to use intellisense. I mean, when you will put a dot in the loop `With msg ... End With`, it will show you all the existing options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing of this code part, please:

```
msg.send

If Issent = True Then
   Range("G" & i).Value = "Sent"
Else
   Range("G" & i).Value = "Not Sent"
End If
```

with this one:

```
Dim Issent As Boolean
   
   On Error Resume Next
    msg.send
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
      Issent = False
   Else
      On Error GoTo 0
      Issent = True
   End If
   
    If Issent = True Then
       Range("G" & i).Value = "Sent"
    Else
       Range("G" & i).Value = "Not Sent"
    End If
```

Edited:
I do not think that the above inserted lines can bother your code smooth operation. Even if not this was the question, please try the next adapted code. It also deals with eventual wrong paths to documents to be attached:

1. Add a reference to `Microsoft Outlook ... Object Library`. Being in VBE (Visual Basic Editor), go: Tools (menu) -> References... Scroll down until you find the above mentioned reference. Check it and press `OK`.
2. Copy the next code instead of yours, or near it (I will change the `Sub` name) and run it:

```
    Sub Send_Multiple_Emails_bis()
     Dim sh As Worksheet, Issent As Boolean, i As Long, last_row As Long
     Dim OA As New Outlook.Application, msg As Outlook.MailItem
    
     Set sh = ActiveSheet ' ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    
     last_row = sh.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    
     For i = 2 To last_row
        Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)
        With msg
            .To = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
            .cc = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
            .Subject = sh.Range("D" & i).Value
            .body = sh.Range("E" & i).Value
            '.display 'un-comment if you want to see each mail sending window
        End With
        
        If sh.Range("F" & i).Value <> "" Then
            If Dir(sh.Range("F" & i).Value) <> "" Then
                msg.Attachments.aDD sh.Range("F" & i).Value
            Else
                Range("G" & i).Value = "Wrong attachment path"
                GoTo NextMail
            End If
        End If
        
        On Error Resume Next
        msg.send
         If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
            Issent = False
         Else
            On Error GoTo 0
            Issent = True
         End If
        
        If Issent = True Then
            Range("G" & i).Value = "Sent"
        Else
            Range("G" & i).Value = "Not Sent"
        End If
    NextMail:
        Set msg = Nothing
     Next i
    
     MsgBox "Mails Sent"
    End Sub
```

I would like to receive some feedback regarding its behavior...

Comment: thank you so much! sorry for delayed response it was a bit busy at work today. I was finally able to test it and it's executing the way I want it.